# How to get less update notification?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Current update schedule is too frequent to me. The editor pops out update reminder every 3-4 days.

[image]

I don't need so frequent update reminder. It's annoying to me. I am only interested in major release.

So how to get less update notification? (Every month or quarter would be preferred).

(Because of the annoyance, currently, I just ignore all update notifications. I understand it could be risky and it's not a good practice)

Current version number looks like: XX.YY.ZZ. How to only subscribe XX.YY update (ignore ZZ update)? Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch to manual updates in the settings (`Ctrl` + `,`).

[image]

This will disable the notification, and checking for updates manually will only be 2 clicks away:

[image]

Comment: After July 2022 update (v1.70),  'Check for Updates...' was moved into the Help menu.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a way for getting less update, only for major update, not disabling it. (Every month or quarter would be preferred).